# Combine multiple files and folders into one file using PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have designed an online editor with which a user can create files and folders on the server. Suppose a user creates the below files and folders.

/docs/abc.txt
/docs/def.txt
/docs/work/assignment.txt

I want to write a PHP script to combine the files into a single ZIP file so that it makes it easier for the user to download them with one click.

The only purpose is that I should get a single file with the directory hierarchy maintained which the user can download and uncompress on his system to get the original files and directory structure back. I don't care even if the ZIP file is not compressed.

**Note that I am using a shared server and do not have access to execute external commands.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class is what you need. Using this you can add directories and file to an archive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have permission to execute an external command, you could use [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to run an external command-line capable ZIP program such as [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using a shared server and do not have the access to execute external commands.